# Express regex match optional param at start and another at the end

Tags: regex, express

Trying to retrieve this routes with optional language code at the start and optional item id at the end:

```
/
/en
/projects
/en/items
/items/folder/1
/en/items/folder/1
```

For now I have this:

```
router.get('/:lang([a-z]{2})?/:rest(*[a-z])?/:item([0-9])?', function(req, res, next) {


}
```

Now I want to exclude with the regex all calls ending in an extension, i.e. filenames.

```
/bundle-5640.js
/styles-5640.css
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the regex you have work for all other files?

Comment: Yes, it captures any valid url ending in an extension; and I want to reject them…

Comment: What is `:lang` in the regex? Won't it match literally to *:lang*?

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I think it's a named capture with a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the url parameter with the actual regex. Never mind!